# Tag info for [netherlands]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The current tag information for [netherlands](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netherlands) reads as following:

> relating to the jurisdiction of a kingdom of "seven provinces" between Belgium and Germany.

I don't know in what era that tag was created, but the Netherlands has had 12 provinces ever since 1986. We've had more than 7 ever since 1796, quite some time ago.

So, either who created this tag (which appears to be [Community](https://law.stackexchange.com/posts/11557/revisions) (which is highly unlikely) but may have been [jimsug](https://law.stackexchange.com/posts/9674/revisions) as well), so I'm guessing it was a deleted user instead) is quite misinformed or the tag is only supposed to be used for historic law (which doesn't appear to be so, based on a quick glance over the questions the tag is used on).

I could simply rectify the situation by editing 'seven' into 'twelve', but I honestly don't know why you'd want to include the amount of provinces in the first place (besides, we're capable and likely to change that amount in the future). So the result might not be up to par with the quality standards of your site (which I, as a passer-by, am not familiar with).

Besides, if we're talking about the "Kingdom of the Netherlands" instead of the Netherlands anyway, the area is more than just what's between Belgium and Germany. Aruba, Curaçao and Sint Maarten are also part of the kingdom, while their location is in the Caribbean. The kingdom has it's own council, so it's not just a shiny name for the same thing as the country the Netherlands itself.

So, the only part the tag got right is it might be about a kingdom. And even that not necessarily.

I'm more than willing to fix this tag, but I'm at somewhat of a loss as to what the tag should cover. Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's funny.

The tag is not just for historic law, and I don't see why it is necessary to characterize the Netherlands as anything other than the country, especially not in the excerpt!  So I just truncated it accordingly.

Thanks for pointing this out.  Most of your exposition would make for a good tag wiki, if you're so inclined!